# How can I specify the IisVirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath in the {Project}.SetParameters.xml file?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, msdeploy

I've been unable to get our TFS build server to stop putting it's local build path in the {Project}.SetParameters.xml file. I'm currently trying to override it using a project parameters.xml file, but can't find the magic combination that will let me override that property. Main problem is that I don't know where that value comes from, so it's difficult to match & override it.

Current result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/MyService" />
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Pool Name" value="MyService" />
  <setParameter name="IisVirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath" value="F:\Builds\59\EAS\MyService.Changeline_1.1.1.0\Sources\API Layer\API_deploy" />
</parameters>
```

I want that last line to be:

Of course, MSFT documentation is lacking in this regard. Here's my current parameters.xml file, that does not work. No build errors, it just doesn't overwrite that IisVirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <parameter name="IisVirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath"
             description="Physical path where files for this Web application will be deployed."
             defaultValue="C:\Program Files\Blah\MyService\API"
             tags="DestinationVirtualDirectory">
    <parameterEntry kind="DestinationVirtualDirectory" scope=".*" match="^F:\\Builds[\w\s\\\.\-]+$" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get that parameters.xml to do anything.

If you create a MyService.wpp.targets file,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069(v=vs.110).aspx

Then you can add an entry into that file.  It will set this value in the setparamters.xml (it wont however set the value inside the zip, which is a bit of a pain, cos  what if the someone just imports the zip.  But this is better than nothing.

C:\Program Files\Blah\MyService\API

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tried it, because we "solved" our problem by switching to Git/Jenkins/Nant.

Comment: +1 for your solution. Having to solve this outside is unfortunate, because it illustrates how difficult and undocumented this feature is.